# My Flutter Emulator is not working in VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

**Error Showing**

cannot launch without active device
Failed to launch Pixel 2 API 28: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
emulator: ERROR: Not enough disk space to run AVD 'Pixel_2_API_28'. Exiting...
  Command

Tried to launch several times checked my RAM memmory also it waas at 50%.I have worked with flutter several times its first time i got the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the **Internal Storage** of your emulator

On the **AVD Manager** of Android Studio, edit your device, click on **Show advanced settings** and change the value your **Internal Storage**

[image]

Comment: After increasing memory it is still showing the error.

Comment: Maybe you need to make a cold boot of your emulator.
If not, you can wipe data but it's not great